# jquery - prepopulate a php text field with session email address

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I had a few ideas on how this would work, but nothing is working so far.

When user logs into php/codeigniter app, email address is stored into session data.  onLoad, I want to prepop a field with the email address of the user that logs in using jquery.

I am using this to output the code on the page for testing:

```
<?php
$userEmail = $this->session->userdata('USER_EMAIL');
echo $userEmail;
?>
```

Comment: Any reason you want to use javascript, when php would work?

Comment: actually I am learning jquery now and enjoying also the app we inherited is an autogenerating form, so getting to the fields via php is a bit tedious. so I want to see if there is a simple means of grabbing the php session data in jquery and displaying it as i want. All, this app has many accounts so I want to be able to drop jquery in when/where needed.

Comment: Does codeigniter automatically start the session for you?  If not you will need to start it yourself before you can get to the data in the session.

Answer (score 4):

Best way to do it, would be to just use php like so:

```
<input type="text" name="userEmail" value="<?php echo htmlentities($userEmail); ?>" />
```

But if you want to use jQuery, just do something like this:

```
$("#userEmailId").val("<?php echo htmlentities($userEmail); ?>");
```

For clarity sake, **session data only exists server-side**. If you want to access it client-side(in jquery), it needs to be in the actual page somewhere, or in a cookie.

Comment: thanks for that clarification - so I can't use jquery [as I would like to] for this issue because I don't want to put this in the main page.  Thank you very much!